# Send SMS using OZEKI to multiple recepients

Tags: php, arrays, ozeki

I have a HTML form with a drop down list, which has my entire buyers list populated from the database. In addition to that, I have an option on the top of the drop down such as :

```
   <select name="sms_buyer">
          <option value="alll">ALL</option>
              <?php 
                  require_once '../model/notifications.php';
                  @$result2=  Notifications::getAllBuyers();
                  while($value2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
              ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $value2['buyer_code']; ?>">
                 <?php echo $value2['buyer_name'] ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

In the Controller I have the following code segment:

```
  function sendNotificationSMS(){

        $sms_buyer=$_REQUEST['sms_buyer'];
        $sms_message=$_REQUEST['sms_message'];
        $sender='MY CLIENT';
        $url='http://localhost:9333/ozeki?';
        $url.="action=sendMessage";
        $url.="&login=admin";
        $url.="&password=abc123";

        $obj=new Notifications();

        if($sms_buyer=='alll'){
            require_once '../model/notifications.php';
            $obj=new Notifications();
            $result=$obj->getAllBuyers();

            while($value=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $rec[]=$value['tel_no'];
            }

            foreach ($rec as $recepient) {
                $url.="&recepient=".urlencode($recepient);
            }
        }
        else{
            $res=$obj->getBuyerTelNo($sms_buyer);
            $sms=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            $recepient=$sms['tel_no'];
            $url.="&recepient=".urlencode($recepient);
        }

        $message=$sms_message;
        $message.=' Thank You.';


        $url.="&messageData=".urlencode($message);
        $url.="&sender=".urlencode($sender);
        file($url);
        header("location:../view/send_notifications.php?s=3#sent");
  }
```

If I type print_r($url), the output which I am intending is not appearing...
Sending SMS to a single recepient is fine. The problem is sending sms to multiple recepients.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you will have to feed the sending function a loop of numbers unless ozeki allows you to send it multiple numbers at once

Comment: @Dagon Can you illustrate your suggestion in a coding format...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String sel = "select parents.parent_contact, Parents.names, students.admno, Students.Names, Examination_lower.Mathematics, Examination_lower.Kiswahili, Examination_lower.English, Examination_lower.Science, Examination_lower.Religion, Examination_lower.Social_studies, Examination_lower.total from parents, students, Examination_lower where parents.parent_contact=students.parent_contact and Examination_lower.admno=students.admno";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sel);
        smnt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String contact = rs.getString("parent_contact");

            String smsSender = "+2547xxxxxx66";
            String smsReceiver = contact;
            String message = jTextArea1.getText();
            String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO "
            + "messageout (Sender,receiver,msg,status) "
            + "VALUES "
            + "('" + smsSender + "','" + smsReceiver + "','" + Message + "','send')";

            if (smnt.executeUpdate(sqlInsert) != 0) {
                System.out.println("OK");

            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            pst.close();
            smnt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a java code, but you can simply format it in PHP, I'm not conversant with PHP but I know this will help you with your knowledge in PHP.

The point is:
1. you select multiple contacts from the database using select query
2. then while results
3. Send message to those contacts(as many as db will have, and as many as your credit can support)